# Paragraph indentation in a list

Tags: lists, indentation, paragraphs

I'm trying to use LaTeX to produce my homework assignments. They're in the form of answering a question sheet, so the answers are formatted in a similar way to the questions, i.e.

1. (a) foo
   (b) foo
   (c) foo
2. foo

I've been answering my questions using enumerative lists. Each \item has a fair number of paragraphs. My problem is that the paragraphs aren't indenting in the usual way by separating them with a blank line. They end up looking like:

Foobar.
Foobar.
Foobar.

I ideally want the first paragraph to have no indentation at the beginning but the subsequent paragraphs to have the first line indented by a standard width. Is there a way to do what I want? If not, is there an easier method for doing my assignments where my answers match the format that the questions are laid out in?

Thanks :-)

Comment: I wonder whether your goal would be better served by messing with the sectioning commands, rather than itemize commands...

Comment: Should "My problem is that the paragraphs aren't indenting in the usual way by separating them with a blank line." read "The paragraphs are not marked by indentation, but by separating them with some vertical space" or did you redefine something?

Answer (score 16):

The `enumerate` environment removes the paragraph indentation, but you may restore that. Afterwards the paragraphs within enumerate would be indented, but not the first one, like desired. For example, create a `myenumerate` environment and use this instead:

```
\newenvironment{myenumerate}{%
  \edef\backupindent{\the\parindent}%
  \enumerate%
  \setlength{\parindent}{\backupindent}%
}{\endenumerate}
```

It could be done even easier using the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate{listparindent=\parindent}
```

For your convenience, here's a complete example. It uses the first redefiniton, but the two `enumitem` lines (and the `enumerate` environment) would give the same result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%
\newenvironment{myenumerate}{%
  \edef\backupindent{\the\parindent}%
  \enumerate%
  \setlength{\parindent}{\backupindent}%
}{\endenumerate}

%
\begin{document}
\begin{myenumerate}
\item
  \begin{myenumerate}
    \item \blindtext

         \blindtext
    \item \blindtext
  \end{myenumerate}
\end{myenumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I recommend to use the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package, it offers many further features for customizing lists.