# How to indent multiline item within enumeration after new paragraph?

Tags: indentation, enumerate

I use the `enumerate` environment with items that contain several paragraphs. How can I achieve standard indentation (all but first line) within one item?
All I tried so far failed:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item default 1 \\ default 2
\item hspace 1 \\ \hspace{1cm} hspace 2
\item indent 1 \\ \indent indent 2
\item This is some multiline text. aaaaa aaaaa  aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa. \\
\phantom{space}And another line, that I'd like to be indented.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Obviously using `phantom` (as I did) is probably the most ugly way to get this behavior.

Comment: some useful information in this answer to the question [Paragraph indentation in a list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6028/579)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never use `\\` in the text, that is a really bad habit, especially when you actually mean **new paragraph**

I tend to use this

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{
  noitemsep,
  listparindent=\parindent,
  parsep=0pt,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item default 1 

  default 2
\item hspace 1 

  hspace 2
\item indent 1 

  indent 2
\item This is some multiline text. aaaaa aaaaa  aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa
  aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa. 

  And another line, that I'd like to be indented.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When saying that something is a bad habit, it would be enlightening -- for new users --  to know why such a thing is a problem. You can make reference to any other posts showing some situation in which such a habit turned into an issue.