# Paragraphs not indenting in enumerate item

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate

For some reason, my paragraphs are not being indented automatically. My file looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathtools,amsthm,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\renewcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\T}{\mathbb{T}}
\newcommand{\Rie}{\mathcal{R}}
\newcommand\abs[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\title{Homework}
\author{My name}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle
\begin{enumerate}
\item blahefjieojf

not indenting?
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

How can I get paragraphs to indent in `\item`?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX! See if this helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5960/paragraph-indentation-in-a-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is set by default because there is a non-zero `\parsep`. It is not recommended, typographically speaking to have both. You can easily change that with the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathtools,amsthm,graphicx}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\renewcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\T}{\mathbb{T}}
\newcommand{\Rie}{\mathcal{R}}
\newcommand\abs[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\title{Homework}
\author{My name}
\usepackage{enumitem}%
\usepackage{lipsum}%

 \begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle
\begin{enumerate}[listparindent=1em, parsep=0pt]
\item blahefjieojf

\lipsum[11]

\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item blahefjieojf

\lipsum[11]

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]